# Why Elasticsearch cluster does not recognizes a superuser on cluster restart?

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a superuser on my 3 node elastic cluster. As seen below the user very well exists, I am pretty sure I am using the correct password. Also it allows me to change the password but at the same time it says user does not exists. 
[image: userslist]

After shutting down all three nodes and restarting again, it started giving security exception.

> {
>       "error": {
>           "root_cause": [
>               {
>                   "type": "security_exception",
>                   "reason": "unable to authenticate user [prashant] for REST request [/_cluster/health]",
>                   "header": {
>                       "WWW-Authenticate": "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
>                   }
>               }
>           ],
>           "type": "security_exception",
>           "reason": "unable to authenticate user [prashant] for REST request [/_cluster/health]",
>           "header": {
>               "WWW-Authenticate": "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
>           }
>       },
>       "status": 401 }

Comment: have you had success with my answer or brought you to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

So all users and their passwords as well as their roles are stored in a system-index **in elasticsearch**. It seems like you've lost your data (= indices) and elasticsearch doesn't recognize the user because there is no entry for that user in the system index.

You should verify that the user really exists by executing a curl/http request against the [GET users API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-get-user.html) **using the built-in elastic user**, which has superuser privileges.